# how to call a mysql procedure from peewee in python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, peewee

How to call a mysql procedure of peewee in python.

I need examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a reference to a cursor by doing:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.callproc(...)
```

I'm not sure if this will work, too, but if you can use regular function syntax, then you can do `fn.ADD_EXTERNAL_CONTACT_INFO(...)` using the `fn` helper.

Comment: This approach works!! But the method to get the cursor is `cursor = db.get_cursor()`. Further a commit may have to be executed (`db.commit()`). Maybe it's possible to add this to the peewee documentation?

Comment: seems to work just fine.
but how do i receive values from a procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
database.execute_sql('call sentence(%s, %s)',(parameter1,parameter2))
```